# Can I use a switch case on C with multiple values?

Tags: c, switch-statement, label, case

I'm working on that famous program that gives the date of tomorrow so I chose to use a `switch` to determine the months with 30 days in one case and the months with 31 days in another.
When I write `case 2:` it works, but when I try to write `case : 4,6,9,11` it shows me an error.  How can I put multiple values in one case?

```
    switch (m) {
      case 2:
        do {
            printf("faire entrer le jour en chiffres ");
            scanf("%d", &j);
        } while (j > 29 || j < 1);
        if (j == 29) {
            j = 1;
            m = m++;
            a = a;
        } else {
            j = j++;
            m = m;
            a = a;
        };
        break;
      case (1||3||5||7||8||10||12) :
        do {
            printf("faire entrer le jour en chiffres \n");
            scanf("%d", &j);
        } while (j < 1 || j > 31);
        if (j == 31) {
            j = 1;
            m = m++;
            a = a;
        } else {
           j++;
           m = m;
           a = a;
        };
        break;
     case 4 6 9 11 :
        do {
            printf("faire entrer le jour par chifre \n");
            scanf("%d", &j);
        } while (j < 1 && j > 30);
        if (j == 30) {
            j = 1;
            m = m;
            a = a;
        } else {
            j = j++;
            m = m;
            a = a;
        };
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a language reference for C? Looking up what you want to know is more efficient than guessing (which is a terrible idea in C, because even if your program appears to work, it doesn't mean it's right), and more efficient than asking on the internet.

Comment: The behavior of `m=m++;` is not defined by the C standard. Do not do that. Use `m = m+1;`, `m += 1;`, or `++m;`. And similarly for `j=j++;`. Also, the statements `m=m;` and `a=a;` are useless.

Comment: You should check the return value from `scanf()` every time you use it to ensure you got the correct number of values converted.

Comment: Don't forget to increment `a` on the last day of décembre.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use separate case labels like

```
case 1: case 3: case 5: case 7: case 8: case 10: case 12:
do {   
    //...
```

Or the above line can be rewritten like

```
case 1: 
case 3: 
case 5: 
case 7: 
case 8: 
case 10: 
case 12:
do {   
    //...
```

Pay attention to that there is no sense to place a null statement after the closing brace as you are doing as for example

```
}else{
  j=j++;
  m=m;
  a=a;
} ; break
^^^^
```

It is better to write

```
}else{
  j=j++;
  m=m;
  a=a;
}
break
```

Answer (score 3):

[@Vlad from Moscow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75345496/2410359) well answers how to use a `switch` case with multiple values.

Yet given the repetitive nature of OP's code, consider a different solution than `switch`.

```
if (m < 1 || m > 12) {
  Handle_Error();
} else {
  static int eom[] = { 0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };      
  do {
    printf("faire entrer le jour par chifre \n");
    scanf("%d",&j);
  } while(j<1 || j>eom[m]);

  if(j == eom[m]) {
    j = 1;
    m++;  // add code for December to adjust `a`
  } else {
    j++;
  }
}
```

Of course we still need some more changes for February and leap years.